# How to search all documents for a specific phrase in macOS?

Tags: macos, search

We've read other questions similar to this and the answers they received but none of the answers proved satisfactory.

We want to search the contents of all documents on our Mac for the two word phrase “ten days.”

We've tried Spotlight and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

- Spotlight did not produce useful results.
- Using <kbd>F</kbd> we specified search of “This Mac,” `kind=any`, `contents=ten days`, `ignore case` and `whole words only`. This search resulted in documents containing only the word “days” and the word “written,” (among others.)

We are not programmers so we don't write code nor do we know how to use commands which are code.  We just want to find the phrase.

Comment: Spotlight (and Command F search) is dependent on meta data, the  availability of which is enabled in System Preferences => Spotlight - Search Results. "Only selected categories will appear in Spotlight search results." I can find a couple dozen hits on my Mac using "ten days" (Spotlight, in quotes).

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to **find a file with a name**
Just go to the terminal 
cd into the following directory (*type cd and keep a spance drag and drop the folder and hit return*)
and type

```
find . | grep -irl "filename"
```

or if want to **find a phrase in all documents** just type

```
grep -irl "phrase" .
```

i - for ignore case
r - recursive 
l - list (remove the l to see all the occurances)
. - is the current directory

Comment: if you are unaware  of the location use sudo find / |grep -irl 'filename|"phrase"' notice there ARE ' ' on both ends of the grep command   side of that command they are needed to 'escape'  the "phrase"

Answer (score 0):

I use [EasyFind](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) (freeware) for that type of search.

It does it the old-fashioned way, of actually reading through everything til it finds what you want.
Slower than Spotlight, but more thorough & better for content & System file searches.

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure: I am the developer of [HoudahSpot](http://www.houdah.com/houdahSpot).

You can use Spotlight at the command line or by the way of a third party front-end to search for phrases. This works as long as the text of the files you are looking for is indexed by Spotlight. I.e. the drive / folder must be indexed and the Spotlight importer in charge of the file must have extracted text content.

In HoudahSpot (use HoudahSpot 3.9 on Mac OS X 10.9.5) you can express your search as:

```
"Text Content" "Contains Phrase" "ten days"
```

HoudahSpot can also show you the query it sends to Spotlight. You can use that query with the [mdfind](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mdfind.1.html) command in Terminal.app. For the above example, the command is:

```
mdfind 'kMDItemTextContent == "*ten days*"c'
```